# Why am I suddenly receiving the HTTP Status Code 412?

Tags: python, google-chrome, webdriver

Im trying to execute some code passing some json data to an api to retrieve some results.  The script was working then suddenly I started getting a 412 response.  At some point chrome updated from version 112.0.5615.49 to 112.0.5615.50.  Im trying to pass the line below but Im not sure if that line is correct and how to get this script working again?  Wait for the next version of the webdriver?  Having a hard time finding an old version of Chrome out there right now with its webdriver.

'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'

Ive tried changing the revision to its current rev, reinstall prior chromes and disable the update.exe, removing prior webdrivers and replacing them with the latest Chrome 112 version.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your post to include a [mre] and read [ask] to receive the best answers.

Comment: "The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) `412 Precondition Failed` client error response code indicates that access to the target resource has been denied." - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/412). Is there a possibility that your code has changed or the server's code has changed?

Comment: It was the servers code, thank you for having me look into that